# Storing Json in Embedded Redis Server

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis

Is it possible to use redisjson module or other redis modules when we are using embedded redis server in java spring boot application? Is it recommended to use embedded redis server?

Currently looking into adding modules for embedded redis server in java spring boot application but couldnt find any details regarding that.

Comment: Why do you want to run embedded Redis in Java?

Comment: Its a client requirement that has come up and want to check the feasibility of it

Comment: how do you run the server embedded?

Comment: It wont be dependent on any server and can run on any environment, like the H2 in-memory database. It will be embedded to the spring boot application and starts along with the application. For reference, https://www.baeldung.com/spring-embedded-redis